# C++ constexpr compiles too fast

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

When I compile a program including:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
constexpr int fib_c(int n)
  {
   if (n<=1) return n;
   return fib_c(n-1)+fib_c(n-2);
  }

int main()
 {
  constexpr int result_c = fib_c(45);
  cout << result_c << "\n";
  return 0;
 }
```

g++ -O3 (version 5.1.0) compiles in 1.2 seconds. It runs in 0 seconds. But it runs in 7.5 seconds when result_c is not declared constexpr.

How can the compilation be so fast? Shouldn't it take at least 7.5 seconds to do what my optimized compiled code does just to get the same value? Why doesn't the compiler generate for me code as fast as the code the compiler generates for itself?

By the way, this problem has been solved by g++ version 10.2.1 in an interesting way: now it fails to compile no matter how high I set -fconstexpr-ops-limit, at least up to any limit I can bear the compilation time. So, what magic code did they take out to slow down constexpr evaluation between versions 5.1.0 and 10.2.1?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/zPcPeYf3W) of how you could memoize your function for O(1) amortized time complexity with runtime evaluation. Note: not thread-safe, and prone to issues if called with large numbers.

Comment: The downside of a compile time approach is that it does not go well with getting Fibonacci numbers at high indices (when a multi-precision integer library is required). E.g. 32-bit **unsigned** integers let you reach `fib(47)`,  64 bits: `fib(93)`, 128 bits (e.g. gcc's `__uint128_t`): `fib(185)` etc. Going to truly high indices (e.g. `fib(1000000)` requires you rethink your algorithm, most likely without any form of explicit/implicit memoization, without the recursive calls, etc: the first 1M fibonacci numbers take 10's or 100's of GB to be stored in memory all at once. Impractical.

Comment: Although it bears the closest resemblance to the mathematical definition of the Fibonacci sequence, recursion is an inappropriate tool for the job. The same calculation can be done iteratively in linear time and constant memory.